# Fail to get existing token using AccountManager in Interceptor of Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, accountmanager

## 一、

When my App launches the MainActivity comes to us, there are not any tokens at this moment so it fails to find token in AccountManager so it goes into LoginActivity.

## 二、

We input account and password the get token from remote server and save it in local AccountManager。then return to MainActivity.

## 三、

When come back MainActivity again. I fail to get the local token even it actually exists now. So the app will go into LoginActivity again. If I exit the app and launch it again at this moment, the Mainactivity is able to get the existing token now.

## Code

I add token into header in Interceptor of Retrofit 2.0 in this way:

```
private volatile static Retrofit jsonInstance;

// Returns singleton class instance
public static Retrofit getJsonInstance(final Context context) {
    if (jsonInstance == null) {
        synchronized (Retrofit.class) {
            if (jsonInstance == null) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request();
                        GitHubAccount gitHubAccount = GitHubAccount.getInstance(context);

                        //Get token here
                        token = gitHubAccount.getAuthToken();

                        request = request.newBuilder()
                                .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token)
                                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Leaking/1.0")
                                //.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.beta+json")
                                .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.raw")
                                        .build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                });


                Gson gson = new Gson();
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                builder.registerTypeAdapter(Event.class, new EventFormatter());
                gson = builder.create();
                jsonInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .client(client)
                        .build();

            }
        }
    }
    return jsonInstance;
}
```

the getAuthToken() method

```
public String getAuthToken() {

    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = manager.getAuthToken(account, ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, (BaseActivity)context, null, null);

    try {
        Bundle result = future.getResult();
        return result.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

    } catch (AccountsException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Auth token lookup failed", e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Auth token lookup failed", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then the procedure of `manager.getAuthToken` will happens in the my custom `AccountAuthenticator`

```
 @Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
    String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        final String password = am.getPassword(account);
        if (password != null) {
            Github github = new GithubImpl(context);
            try {
                //Get token from server
                authToken = github.createToken(account.name,password);
            } catch (GithubError githubError) {
                githubError.printStackTrace();
                authToken = "";
            } catch (AuthError authError) {
                authError.printStackTrace();
                authToken = "";
            } catch (OverAuthError overAuthError) {
                overAuthError.printStackTrace();
                authToken = "";
            }
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Try to get AuthToken password is empty");
        }
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {

        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        return result;
    }
    // If we get here, then we couldn't access the user's password - so we
    // need to re-prompt them for their credentials. We do that by creating
    // an intent to display our AuthenticatorActivity.

    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);

    return bundle;
}
```

## Project

The total project is here
https://github.com/Leaking/WeGit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are saving the token in a async process and the saving method is slower than the Get method.